# Why SAML request does not contain any credentials?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am reading documentation about [microsoft azure active directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#authnrequest). Here request sample:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    ID="id6c1c178c166d486687be4aaf5e482730"
    Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T03:28:54.1839884Z"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.contoso.com</Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

As you can see this does not contains any login or pass. Why? How azure figure out actual credentials?

Comment: This request tells the IDP to display a login page. The credentials are entered there.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication request in SAML is a trigger that initiates a sequence that leads to authentication of a principal and subsequent assertion with claims about this principal.

From [SAML 2.0 spec](http://saml.xml.org/saml-specifications):

> When a principal (or an agent acting on the principal's behalf) wishes
>   to obtain assertions containing authentication statements to establish
>   a security context at one or more relying parties, it can use the 
>   authentication request protocol to send an  message
>   element to a SAML authority and  request that it return a 
>   message containing one or more such assertions.